# Script only works when alert() is called

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alert

If I were to add in the alert() in the mainDownload() then the script will run and download a file from s3. But without it, it just skips the whole script after clicking the download button. Could be a timing issue but im not sure.

```
async mainDownload() {

  try {
    presignedGETURL = await this.generatePresignedUrl();

    await this.downloadFile(presignedGETURL);
    // console.log(data)
    //alert("hello")
    //return "done"
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err caught due to...>", err)
    alert(err + " error in mainDownload")

  }
}

async generatePresignedUrl() {
  try {
    let bucketParams = {
      Bucket: //bucketname,
        Key: keyFile
    }

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    presignedGETURL = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', bucketParams)
    console.log('presigned url obtained from s3: ', presignedGETURL)
    //alert(presignedGETURL)
    return presignedGETURL;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error call during call s3".concat(err))
    throw err;
  }
}

async downloadFile(presignedGETURL) {
    
    const url = presignedGETURL
    
    axios({
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).then((response) => {
      const test = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = test
      link.setAttribute('download', 'helloWorld.pdf')
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click();
    })
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `downloadFile`, which you left out. It's not waiting for the download to complete before resolving.

Comment: I guess i missed adding the downloadFile function in the example...oops. But thats not the reason.

Comment: Try using `await axios(...)` in `downloadFile`.